# Why is |z|^3 not analytic at origin even though it is differentiable, how do we apply Cauchy reimann equations to it?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is |z|^3 not analytic at the origin?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Formal_definition): $$ \frac{\partial \lvert z \rvert^3}{\partial \overline{z}} =  \frac{\partial (z \overline z)^{3/2}}{\partial \overline{z}} = \tfrac32 \lvert z \rvert \cdot z. $$ This vanishes only for $z=0$, while for holomorphic functions it vanishes identically.

Answer (score 0):

A complex function is analytic at $z_0$ if and only if it is differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_0$. Your function is differentiable only at the origin.